# Insert a draft data to a datatable using modal before saving all draft values

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, modal

I making a lightning component that can do the following:

1. Click a button to open a modal
2. Enter required Account details and hit the save button, this will save the details as a draft to the datatable
3. click a save all button that will save all of the draft records added in the datatable

Below is my code:

component:

```
<aura:component controller="accountDataClass" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="recordList" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchData" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="String" default="Name"/>
<aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="string" default="asc" />
<aura:attribute name="isModalOpen" type="boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="typeMap" type="Map"/>
<aura:attribute name="industryMap" type="Map"/>
<aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" default="{'sobjectType':'Account', 'Name': '', 'Phone': '', 'Type': '', 'Industry': ''}" />

<!-- <aura:handler event=”force:refreshView” action=”{!c.handleRowAction}” /> -->
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />

<aura:attribute name="refreshCount" type="Integer" default="0"/>    
<aura:attribute name="refreshFlag" type="boolean" default="false"/> 

<lightning:card iconName="standard:account" title="Accounts">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <aura:set attribute="actions">
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" verticalAlign="end">
            <div class="slds-p-right_medium">
                <lightning:input type="search" placeHolder="Search" aura:id="SearchBox" onchange="{!c.searchTable}" />
            </div>    
            <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" label="New Account" title="New Account" onclick="{!c.openModal}" />
        </lightning:layout>
    </aura:set>
    <!-- /HEADER -->
    
    <!-- DATATABLE -->
    <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner" style="height: 400px">
        <lightning:datatable keyField="id" 
                             data="{!v.recordList}"
                             columns="{!v.columns}"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                             resizeColumnDisabled="true"
                             showRowNumberColumn="true"
                             onsort="{!c.updateSorting}"
                             sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"
                             onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction }"
                             sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"  />
    </div>
    <!-- /DATATABLE -->        
</lightning:card>

<!-- BUTTONS -->
<div class="buttons-bottom">
    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.refreshComponent}" class="slds-button-group slds-button slds-button--neutral">Refresh Table</lightning:button>
    <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Save All</lightning:button>
</div>
<!-- /BUTTONS -->

<!-- MODAL -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModalOpen}">
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_small">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <!-- MODAL HEADER -->
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" size="large" onclick="{! c.closeModal }" alternativeText="close" variant="bare-inverse" class="slds-modal__close"/>
                <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">New Account</h2>
            </header>
            <!-- /MODAL HEADER -->
            
            <!-- MODAL BODY -->
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <lightning:input name="accountName" type="text" required="true" maxlength="50" label="Account Name" value="{!v.account.Name}" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <lightning:input name="accountPhone" type="phone" maxlength="11" label="Phone" value="{!v.account.Phone}" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <lightning:select aura:id="typePicklist" value="{!v.account.Type}" onchange="{!c.handleTypeOnChange}" name="typePicklist" label="Type" required="true">
                        <option value="">--None--</option>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.typeMap}" var="type" indexVar="key">
                            <option text="{!type.value}" value="{!type.key}" selected="{!type.key==v.account.Type}" />
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <lightning:select aura:id="industryPicklist" value="{!v.account.Industry}" onchange="{!c.handleIndustryOnChange}" name="industryPicklist" label="Industry" required="true">
                        <option value="">--None--</option>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.industryMap}" var="industry" indexVar="key">
                            <option text="{!industry.value}" value="{!industry.key}" selected="{!industry.key==v.account.Industry}" />
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /MODAL BODY -->
            
            <!-- MODAL FOOTER -->
            <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick="{! c.closeModal }"/>
                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" title="Save" onclick="{!c.submitDetails}"/>
            </footer>
            <!-- /MODAL FOOTER -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
</aura:if>
<!-- /MODAL --></aura:component>
```

controller.js

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'Name', fieldName:'Name', sortable:true,type:'text'},
        {label: 'Phone', fieldName:'Phone', sortable:true,type:'text'},
        {label: 'Industry', fieldName:'Industry', sortable:true,type:'text'},
        {label: 'Type', fieldName:'Type', sortable:true,type:'text'},
        {label: 'Action', type:'button', typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Delete',
            title: 'Delete',
            name: 'delete',
            value: 'delete',
            disabled: false,
            iconPosition: 'left',
            iconName: 'utility:delete',
            variant: "destructive"
        }},
    ]);
        
    helper.getAccounts(component, helper);
    helper.getIndustryPicklist(component, event);
    helper.getTypePicklist(component, event);
},

updateSorting: function (component, event, helper) {
    var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
    var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
    component.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
    component.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
    helper.sortData(component, fieldName, sortDirection);
},

searchTable: function (component, event, helper) {
    var allRecords = component.get("v.searchData");
    var searchFilter = event.getSource().get("v.value").toUpperCase();
    var tempArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<allRecords.length; i++) {
        if((allRecords[i].Name && allRecords[i].Name.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1) ||
           (allRecords[i].Phone && allRecords[i].Phone.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1) ||
           (allRecords[i].Industry && allRecords[i].Industry.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1) ||
           (allRecords[i].Type && allRecords[i].Type.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1)) {
            tempArray.push(allRecords[i]);
        }
    }
    component.set("v.recordList", tempArray);
},

handleRowAction: function (component, event, helper) {
    var action = event.getParam('action');
    switch (action.name) {
        case 'delete':
            helper.deleteRecord(component, event)
            break;
    }
},

//handle Industry Picklist Selection
handleIndustryOnChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var industry = component.get("v.account.Industry");
},

handleTypeOnChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var type = component.get("v.account.Type");
},

refreshComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    //$A.enqueueAction(action);
},

openModal: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Set isModalOpen attribute to true
    component.set("v.isModalOpen", true);
},

closeModal: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Set isModalOpen attribute to false  
    component.set("v.isModalOpen", false);
},

submitDetails: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Set isModalOpen attribute to false
    //Add your code to call apex method or do some processing
    /*var myData = component.get("!v.recordList");
    myData.push({
        Name: "!v.accountName",
        Phone: "!v.accountPhone",
        Industry: "!v.typePicklist",
        Type: "!v.industryPicklist"
    });
    component.set("v.recordList", myData);*/
    
    component.set("v.isModalOpen", false);
}, })
```

helper

```
({
getAccounts : function(component, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getAccountList");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        var data;
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.recordList", result);
            component.set("v.searchData", result);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

getIndustryPicklist: function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.getIndustry");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            var industryMap = [];
            for(var key in result){
                industryMap.push({key: key, value: result[key]});
            }
            component.set("v.industryMap", industryMap);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

getTypePicklist: function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.getType");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            var typeMap = [];
            for(var key in result){
                typeMap.push({key: key, value: result[key]});
            }
            component.set("v.typeMap", typeMap);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

sortData: function (component, fieldName, sortDirection) {
    var fname = fieldName;
    var data = component.get("v.recordList");
    var reverse = sortDirection !== 'asc';
    data.sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse))
    component.set("v.recordList", data);
},

sortBy: function (field, reverse) {
    var key = function(x) {return x[field]};
    reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
    return function (a, b) {
        return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
    }
},

deleteRecord : function(component, event) {
    component.set("v.isLoading", true);
    var accountRec = event.getParam('row');        
    var action = component.get("c.delAccount");
    action.setParams({
        "accountRec": accountRec
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        component.set("v.isLoading", false);            
        if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS" ) {
            var rows = component.get('v.results');
            var rowIndex = rows.indexOf(accountRec);
            rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
            component.set('v.results', rows);
            this.showToast("Success!", "success", "The record has been deleted successfully.");
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }
        else{
            this.showToast("ERROR","error",JSON.stringify(response.getError())); 
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    //component.refreshDataTable();
},

showToast : function(title, type, message) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    if(toastEvent){
        toastEvent.setParams({"title": title,"type": type,"message": message}).fire();
    }
    else{
        alert(message);
    }
}, })
```

apex

```
public with sharing class accountDataClass {
@AuraEnabled //
public static List<Account> getAccountList() {
    List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Industry, Type FROM Account ORDER BY Name ASC];
    
    if(accountList != null && accountList.size() > 0) {
        return accountList;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

@AuraEnabled // GET TYPE PICKLIST VALUES
public static Map<String, String> getType(){
    Map<String, String> typeOptions = new Map<String, String>();
    // GET TYPE FIELD DESCRIBE
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.Type.getDescribe();
    // GET TYPE PICKLIST VALUES
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pList = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry p: pList) {
        // PUT TYPE PICKLIST VALUE AND LABEL IN MAP
        typeOptions.put(p.getValue(), p.getLabel());
    }
    return typeOptions;
}

@AuraEnabled // GET INDUSTRY PICKLIST VALUES
public static Map<String, String> getIndustry(){
    Map<String, String> industryOptions = new Map<String, String>();
    // GET INDUSTRY FIELD DESCRIBE
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.Industry.getDescribe();
    // GET INDUSTRY PICKLIST VALUES
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pList = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry p: pList) {
        // PUT INDUSTRY PICKLIST VALUE AND LABEL IN MAP
        industryOptions.put(p.getValue(), p.getLabel());
    }
    return industryOptions;
}

@AuraEnabled // DELETE ACCOUNT RECORD
public static void delAccount(Account accountRec){
    delete accountRec;
} }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "draft", and is there a specific reason for this two-step saving? If the second save is not performed do you expect the first save to be rolled back (for me that is the implication of "draft")?

Comment: what i mean by draft is inserting a new row of data entered from the modal, which is only visible in the datatable